# How to post string with FeignClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

The server gets request body with using `request.getInputStream()`.

The client code:

```
@FeignClient(name="composer-agent")
public interface ComposerClient {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/agent/import_bp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String importBlueprints(String payload);
}
```

But i get an exception:

```
Caused by: feign.FeignException: status 500 reading ComposerClient#importBlueprints(String); content:
{"timestamp":"2017-10-19T06:15:47-0400","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"MIME type may not contain reserved characters"}
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62)
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:91)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:108)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:301)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:297)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
    ... 144 common frames omitted
```

Also i try to set `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` or other values,  or add `@RequestBody`, but i get the same exception.

So how can i deal this problem? Thanks.

Comment: `"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"MIME type may not contain reserved characters"`. Your mimetype seems to contain illegal characters. So the question is: Which mimetype are you using (its not shown in the code)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1731) in Feign 9.3.0 when the underlying HTTP client is the Apache HTTP client. The solution is to upgrade the `feign-httpclient` dependency. For example:

```
compile "io.github.openfeign:feign-httpclient:9.5.0"
```

Comment: I use spring-cloud, and the dependency is: 
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: i create the client with a interface. Any suggestion?

Comment: Add the dependency I documented with a version that matches that which is brought in by the cloud starter. If the version brought in by the cloud starter has the bug, upgrade your version of spring-cloud. Maven has a target that shows all dependency versions to help you.

Comment: I got the error. i defined an interceptor using `feign.RequestInterceptor` and i transfer all headers transparently. So if the request `content-type` is different from that configed in the @FeighClient, the exception occured.